# Atach search bar in bootstrap Navbar when mobile window is display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to make the search bar stay to the top next to the navbar-brand logo, but every time i reach 768 pixels in the screen, the search bar goes to the bottom, i want to have the search bar at the same level of the navbar-brand but can´t achieve that yet, here is the code I'm using

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top  navColor">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="img/Logo.png" alt="" class="navLogo">

                </a>
            </div>
            <!--navbar-header-->

                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 navbar-left">
                    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group barraBuscar">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" name="q">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 navbar-right">
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul id="menu" class="navbar-nav" style=" list-style-type: none;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x iconos" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Promociones"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-2x iconos" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Videos"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x iconos" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Galeria"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-2x iconos" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Notificaciones"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-2x iconos" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Publicaciones"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-2x iconos" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Bolsa de trabajo"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div> <!--container-fluid-->
 </nav>
```

and here is the css

```
.navColor{
    background-color: #1d88c5 !important;
    border-color: #1d88c5 !important;
}

.navLogo {
    max-width:30px;
}

.barraBuscar{   
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use show/hide bootstrap blocks. i mean change the page navbar display on different size of the screen

http://blog.templatemonster.com/2014/10/24/bootstrap-3-grid-system-guide/